# Powershell WebClient.DownloadFile not overwriting

Tags: powershell

I am trying to download a file from reporting services. The first time I run this code it works fine, but the next time it wont overwrite the first ones downloaded file. I have tried adding **Remove-Item $file** before I create the WebClient object, but when I do this I get the error **The process cannot access the file 'D:\Work\RawMaterialCodes.xls' because it is being used by another process.**, the process being Powershell itself. I have tried calling **$webClient.Dispose()** thinking this might release the file, but no luck.
Does anyone have any ideas how I can overwrite the downloaded file and/or remove it before the next download attempt?

```
$reportServer = "http://localhost/ReportServer_TRITON"
$reportName = "RawMaterialCodes"
$file = "D:\Work\RawMaterialCodes.xls"

$startDate = "2014-01-22"
$endDate = "2014-01-24"
$category = "Cat1"
$destination = ""

$reportUrl = $reportServer + "?/" + $reportName + "&StartDate=" + $startDate + "&EndDate=" + $endDate + "&Category=" + $category + "&Destination=" + $destination + "&rs:Format=Excel"

$webClient = new-object System.Net.WebClient
$webClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($userName, $password, $domain)
$webClient.DownloadFile($reportUrl, $file)

$mailMessage = new-object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage
$mailMessage.From = $emailFrom
$mailMessage.To.Add($emailTo)
$mailMessage.Subject = $emailSubject
$mailMessage.Body = $emailBody
$attachment = new-object System.Net.Mail.Attachment($file, 'text/plain')
$mailMessage.Attachments.Add($attachment)

$smtpClient = New-Object System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpServer, 25)
$smtpClient.EnableSsl = $enableSsl
if ($smtpAuthUsername -ne "")
{
  $smtpClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($smtpAuthUsername,   $smtpAuthPassword)
}
$smtpClient.Send($mailMessage)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$mailMessage` is keeping an open handle to your file. Add

```
$mailMessage.Dispose()
```

at the end of the script and you should be able to overwrite.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything wrong with the code as you have it written.  Disposing the `WebClient` is unnecessary here with respect to freeing up the file as it doesn't keep a handle to it.  The most likely cause of this error is another piece of your code or another program which is opening the file and not properly disposing of it.

I would first assume it was my code at fault and carefully audit any other place I manipulated this file and see if I accidentally left a handle to it open

Comment: @Energ1ser seems like it's most likely held by another process then.  Have you closed down all apps which oculd be referring to this file?